# Passing a object from server to client with Vaadin

Tags: javascript, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to pass an object from the server to the client with Vaadin:

My object:

```
public class MyObject {
    public String name;
    public int value;
}
```

Then I have a component extending `AbstractJavaScriptComponent`, which has this:

```
public void doStuff(MyObject obj) {
    callFunction("doStuff", obj);
}
```

The JavaScript function `doStuff` is then correctly called, but the argument I get doesn't have the properties `name` and `value`, the type of the argument is correct (`MyObject`).

`MyObject` is part of the WidgetSet (it is in the *.client namespace), though I don't know if that is even a must..

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well just for reference, I'll answer it myself:

Even though `callFunction` says that it can handle Objekts/JavaBeans, it seems to me that it actually cannot.
But this way it works:

Put something like this in your WidgetSet:

```
public interface MyComponentClientRpc extends ClientRpc {
    public void doStuff(MyObject obj);
}
```

Then instead of `callFunction` use `getRpcProxy(MyComponentClientRpc.class).doStuff(obj);`

And put something like this in your JS-Connector:

```
this.registerRpc({
    doStuff : function(obj) {
        alert(obj);
    },
});
```

I learned about it here: https://vaadin.com/de/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using%20complex%20Java%20types%20from%20JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

callFunction utilizes the underline JSON marshal/unmarshal mechanism. So you should make your transport object to implement "org.json.JSONString" interface. e.g.

```
public class MyObject implements JSONString, Serializable {
    public String name;
    public int value;

    @Override
    public String toJSONString() {
        return String.format("{\"name\":\"%s\",\"value\":%d}", name, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just debugged into the code.

The problem is that `callFunction()` accepts an `Object[]`. Thus the type that the JsonCodec gets as a hint is `Object.class` and not the type of the items in the `Object[]`.

I found out a dirty workaround for now:

```
MyOptions options = new MyOptions();
options.foo = "bar";
options.count = 1;
callFunction("myFunction",
             JsonCodec.encode(options , null, MyOptions.class, null).getEncodedValue())
```